# How to detect any error that occurred in asynchronous processing

Tags: apex

When updating Contact's email address matched, we implemented a trigger to update the email address and user name of the related user object (community user). (Using @future)

If you specify a user name that has already been set with the contact's email address, you can not duplicate the user name, so an error will occur in @future, but it will be detected at the time of Contact update that this error occurred Is it possible to do it?

Comment: are you maintaining any error log separately when exception is getting generated. Share your code for exception handling

Comment: @SantanuBoral
Thank you!
So, as a countermeasure, is it fundamental to implement a process that try catch asynchronous processing and throw an error mail if an error occurs?

Comment: Asynchronous code errors cannot be caught in the source context where the asynchronous code was called from. It is run at a later time, after the initial code finishes (the trigger, in this example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is work around you can go ahead with this : -

1. create one object with fields which will stores the exception details.
2. create on generic method which actually create the exception.
3. In your future method catch block just called that generic method, so what the method do when any error occur in the future method it will create a record in your custom object.
4. by creating that record, one you will do round of analysis after certain interval and two you can send an email on the creation of the record to anyone.

i think it will solve your purpose.